# Cannot find symbol variable music

Tags: cannot-find-symbol

I had a question before I edited this and it got answered*

--
I am having a problem where when I try to use a variable, it says 'Cannot find symbol variable music' (https://gyazo.com/7fc2b625fd9d83e76baaa9c3436ecde4) 
when I'm trying to build, I have tried adding it as a class but when I attempt that it says: Generated source files should not be edited.

I also attempted putting the class into a different file which I found, ([Generated source files should not be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886782/generated-source-files-should-not-be-edited))

But that does not do any good either. (https://gyazo.com/2d94550dfe8f0a4c29a1b04cf10b3891)
(https://gyazo.com/66f75d3f56ea0b464d2eacc669289ea9)

Any help?

Comment: Are you already perform gradle build? To ensure that the dependencies already installed on your project

Comment: You need to put the `import android.view.View;` at the top of the file by the other `import` statements.

Comment: Also if you're using Android Studio (or IntelliJ) you can put your cursor on the class name (eg `View`) and hit `Alt-Enter` and it will automatically import it for you.

Comment: Okay I completely got that fixed now, thank you. Now I just need help with a different question, I will edit this main question to fix it, but,